# Why is it necessary to call `toBlocking` before `single`?

Tags: observable, rx-java

I'm exploring a Swagger-generated Java API. In the generated client file, I see two methods like this:

```
public Observable<UserAccountView> createUserAccount(/* params omitted  */) {
   /* body omitted */
}

public UserAccountView createUserAccountSynchronously(/* params omitted */) {
  return createUserAccount(/*params*/).toBlocking.single();
}
```

I've read the RxJava docs and related resources but since I'm new to this I still find myself thinking `toBlocking` shouldn't be needed here-- doesn't blocking/non-blocking lose its meaning for a Single? Is there such a thing  as a blocking Single?

Clearly I'm not fully grasping the relationship between the two methods. I am thinking that `single()` is extracting a singular event from an observable before unsubscribing. Why should `toBlocking` be needed in order to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `toBlocking()` call is there so that the method returns `UserAccountView` instead of `Observable<UserAccountView>`. [`toBlocking()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#toBlocking()) converts the `Observable` into a [`BlockingObservable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/BlockingObservable.html), and calling [`BlockingObservable.single()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/BlockingObservable.html#single--) returns whatever item is emitted by the `BlockingObservable`, as long as it only emits one item before completing (more or less than one results in an error being emitted).

If you were to call `Observable.single()` without converting it to a `BlockingObservable` in RxJava1, it would return an `Observable<UserAccountView>` that emits only a single item, if the Observable completes after emitting one item. In RxJava2, this API is improved so that the equivalent operator, `Observable.singleOrError()`, returns a `Single<UserAccountView>`.

Blocking/non-blocking does not lose its meaning for a `Single` (or in this case, an `Observable` that will only emit a single item). Depending on how you've set up your Schedulers (e.g. using `subscribeOn()`, `observeOn()` or an operator that uses a `Scheduler`), you can have a `Single`/`Observable` that only emits its one item asynchronously after doing processing in some worker thread. So, if the caller of `createUserAccount()` is running in the main thread of the application, the `Observable<UserAccountView>` could return immediately, and emit its result downstream on a worker thread after a few seconds, without the main thread ever being blocked. On the other hand, using `createUserAccountSynchronously()` will block the main thread until `Observable<UserAccountView>` emits its one item.

Generally in reactive applications you avoid using `toBlocking()`, but sometimes you need to bridge between the reactive world and the non-reactive, blocking world, and that's where `toBlocking()` can be useful.

Comment: Slightly throws me off that the `.single()` method is essentially unrelated to the `Single` class. This was very helpful though, thank you.

Comment: @temporary_user_name Yeah, that method is named very poorly, which is why they changed the API in RxJava2 to actually return a `Single`.

Comment: One last question - I just looked through the docs on the methods for the RxJava2 Single class - is there not a standard way to get the value out of it? The RxJava2 equivalent of the RxJava1 `.single()`? It doesn't look like there was.

Comment: @temporary_user_name Yes, you would use `Single.blockingGet()`.